# Does Unity3D let you code with Java?

Tags: java, game-engine

I have been searching but I get the mixed up answers with Java and Javascript. Basically I am wondering if Unity3D lets me make games with Java? I want to make browser based games, not android.

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with C# or JavaScript, but I can assure you if you're comfortable with Java, C# and JavaScript shouldn't be very hard to adjust to. However, I personally prefer C# when it comes to Unity: I find most code-related questions are answered using (or referring to) C#, and JavaScript doesn't really feel right to me outside of Web Development.

Comment: Also, Unity can build browser-compatible games using WebGL: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html

Answer (score 7):

Currently unity3d doesn't support java.

**According to unity3d website.**

> Scripting with Unity brings you fast iteration and execution and the
> strength and flexibility of a world-leading programming environment.
> Scripting is uncluttered, straightforward and incredibly fast. In
> Unity, you write simple behavior scripts in JavaScript, C# or Boo. All
> three languages are easy to use and run on the Open Source .NET
> platform, Mono, with rapid compilation times.

[What Language is Used To Develop Using Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989689/what-language-is-used-to-develop-using-unity)

http://unity3d.com/unity/workflow/scripting

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, you write simple behavior scripts in C# or JavaScript (UnityScript). Both languages are easy to use and run on the integrated scripting runtimes.

Read more: https://unity3d.com/unity/workflow/scripting

As stated above, Unity as of now don't support java coding.

For Java, libGDX is the best option: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Though Unity has better support and documentation, libGDX is also really powerful.

Clash of the Olympians is a popular game made with libGDX
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ironhide.games.clashoftheolympians